# marketing style of fairness products

Tags: terminology, formality

If you have seen any ad of fairness related products, most of them show women who are disadvantaged by their complexion. Say, they show she isn't selected for a job interview because she isn't "fair" and confident. Then towards the end the ad shows that she is trying for the same job opportunity (looking fair this time), and she nails the interview - all is happy this time.

What *kind* of marketing is this?

Comment: In the UK this kind of marketing is called illegal.

Comment: Not too sure if this is suitable for English Language & Usage, but I can't recommend a better site - there's certainly no marketing SE. If other people say it's off-topic, you might try [user experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Regrettable, overly obvious, and sadly pragmatic. If bigotry is influencing hiring, even unintentionally or unknowingly, and being able to "pass" is the cost of making a living, the marketer is helping meet an unfortunate need. The problem here is not with the applicant using the product, the manufacturer, or the marketer. It's with the warped hiring practice and its practitioners.

Comment: Is the question about the cause-and-effect style of narrative in the advertisement? Or about the ethics?

Comment: This appears to be a question about marketing ethics, not English.

Answer (score 1):

This general class of advertising that attempts to coerce potential customers into buying products using unethical tactics like the *[negative reinforcement](http://allpsych.com/psychology101/reinforcement.html)* described above is appropriately named ***manipulative advertising***.

According to [this article](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/examples-manipulative-advertising-11668.html), manipulative advertising "uses misguided promises of desired results to convince customers to purchase a product". The article also explicitly mentions "attractiveness" as a method that advertisers frequently use to manipulate viewers, which seems to correspond with the unethical stratagems in your example.

Because the advertisement is also targeted towards a specific demographic (women who are self-conscious about how they physically appear towards potential employers), it could also be considered a form of *[targeted advertising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Targeted_advertising)*.